# Node server not starting with forever & cron on reboot

Tags: cron, forever

I want to start the below app always on reboot with crontab.

**/home/pi/projects/weatherpi/index.js**

I have a forever.json to start the app

Now while the below command entered directly to command prompt works just fine:

**/usr/local/bin/forever start /home/pi/projects/forever.json > /dev/null 2>&1**

The below entered to "crontab -e" does not start the forever task.

**@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /home/pi/projects/forever.json > /dev/null 2>&1**

Please explain what I'm doing wrong / how to correctly start the server with crontab on startup.